# Change Form ShowInTaskbar property programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanna change change Form ShowInTaskbar property programmatically in order not showing my main form in taskbar when I open a child form. I have try this but it seems this solution does not exist:

```
Form1.showintaskbar = false;
```

Comment: read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an instance property not static. You need to access it via an instance:

```
this.ShowInTaskBar = false;

// or simply
ShowInTaskBar = false;
```